# MongoDB: Querying collection and filtering by array in another collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collections, users and a record of users activity.
My users collection is simple:

```
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b29c78f491172cfe8b049"), 
        "created" : ISODate("2020-07-12T15:18:31.319+0000"), 
        "lastLogin" : ISODate("2020-07-12T15:18:31.319+0000"), 
        "name" : {
            "first" : "Pedro", 
            "last" : "Perez"
        },
        "city" : "New York"
}
```

And the records collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0fb901b320f5ec21269279"), 
    "userId" : ObjectId("5f0b29c78f491172cfe8b04a"), 
    "record" : [
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0b29c78f491172cfe8b049"), 
            "name" : "Pedro", 
            "type" : "like"
        }, 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0b29c78f491172cfe8b04b"), 
            "name" : "Rivaldo", 
            "type" : "fold"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, userId is a foreign key for the user document.

I, as the user (Ex _id : 20) I am performing the query. I want to query the users collection and find users with certain fields (city, name, etc), and also, who doesn't contain any registry of me (user _id: 20) in his records array.

Any idea how to do it? I have tried with $lookup and other operators but without luck.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check if any filtered user doesn't exist inside the `records` field, you can perform this simple aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "name.last": "Perez"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "articles",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "records.user",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      users: {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  }
  //Remove extra field
  //,{
  //  $unset: "users"
  //}
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k47gilZNV0U)

Comment: Hello @Valijon. Yes more or less is the idea, but there is a detail. I want to check that a certain user (passed by parameter, by _id) doesn't exist in the record array, not the current user of the lookup. So, if that certain user doesn't exist in the array and the match fields are correct, then I return the current user.
Probably I did not explain myself correctly in the question.

Comment: @carrasc0 it would be nice if you explain that detail with example, because `the current user doesn't exist there` I've interpreted as filtered user

Comment: No problem. This is the case:

I, as the user 20 I am performing the query. I want to query the users collection and find users with certain fields (city, name, etc), and also, who doesn't contain any registry of me (user 20) in his records array.

When I say "current user" I mean the one who is performing the query, that's the one I need to check doesn’t exist in the records array of the filtered user.

My apologies for the bad explanation.

Comment: @carrasc0 Edit your post please

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first of all, create a foreign key that is easier to read so that even while you copy-paste it, it isn't so hard.

> `db.users.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"records", localField:"_id",`
> `foreignField:"userId", as:"users"}}])`

function will work on this. It seems that you haven't noticed that your "userId" of the records collection does not match with the "_id" field of users collection.

Look at your `_id : ObjectId("5f0b29c78f491172cfe8b049")`

---

Look at your `userId : ObjectId("5f0b29c78f491172cfe8b04a")`

I hope you noticed that the 049 has been replaced with 04a

Check it, you'll find your answer :)